# Append object to array in Swift 3

Tags: swift

Having a bit of trouble trying to push objects that I query from Parse into an array that I can use in a UITableView.

Here's my code.

```
var locations = [AnyObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Query the Locations class.
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Location")

    query.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    self.locations.append(object)
                }
                self.venueTable.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: (error!) (error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return locations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let locationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locationCell", for: indexPath)

    let location = locations[indexPath.row]

    locationCell.textLabel?.text = location

    return locationCell
}
```

After the for loop, locations is full of the parse data, but not sure how to access it when pushing it to the `locationCell`

Answer (score 3):

The type you set for locations is [AnyObject] so that won't work when you try to set the labels text property as it isn't a string.

Instead set it to [PFObject] and then use PFObject's function objectForKey to get the relevant string value from your retrieved object.

Eg

```
var locations = [PFObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Query the Locations class.
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Location")

    query.findObjectsInBackground {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {

                self.locations = objects

                self.venueTable.reloadData()

            }

         } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        print("Error: (error!) (error!.userInfo)")
        }

    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     return locations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let locationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locationCell", for: indexPath)

    let location = locations[indexPath.row]

    locationCell.textLabel?.text = location.objectForKey("property name here") as? String

    return locationCell
}
```